# How to implement offline map in web application and where can i get the map tiles for download?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

currently i am trying to do a offline map feature in web application. When their is no internet connection i want  to load map tiles from my application it self .

How can i have the tile images stored with in my application during the network is available and further use it on offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use leaflet with an offline caching option, something like: https://github.com/tbicr/OfflineMap/tree/master/leaflet_idb_sql_site

You can find more options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036880/how-to-make-offline-mapsusing-leaflet-osm-by-caching)

Comment: Thanks  @ Ando I found one more interesting solution http://offlinegooglemapsgooglejavascriptv3.blogspot.in/2013/05/offline-google-maps-google-javascript.html

Comment: Looks interesting - should I ask if the google maps based solution is within their terms of use? :)