# Raster Map for leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, raster

i'm developping an app using leaflet. I need to have some map datas offline on my device.

To do that i have tried to download some tiles of openstreetmap.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to create Raster images of my zones, and how i can add them on leaflet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you requirements, it might be a lot of data (the whole OpenStreetmap [tileset would consume 54TB disk space](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_disk_usage)).

[Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached/](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached) might be a solution for you, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721312/using-pouchdb-as-an-offline-raster-map-cache) has some notes on a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer to loading and displaying a single image over specific bounds of the map, georeference specific image using example code

**Example 1:**

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Full resource can be find here:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay

**Example 2:**

Or something little more robust from this great and detailed step by step tutorial:

http://build-failed.blogspot.hr/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html

Hope it helps